# Land and Moon Druid differences in spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid

I wanted to ask what the exact differences between land and moon Druids are or more precisely, which spells do moon Druids get?

As far as I have seen land Druids get the spells of the circle they choose (ie. forest, desert, arctic, ...). How does that work for moon Druids, I didn't find anything in the PHB. Do they get all the spells in the druid spell list minus the spells of forest, desert, arctic, ...?

Answer (score 13):

*All* Druids get all the spells listed in their spell list detailed in PHB 208. It doesn't matter the circle, any druid can prepare spells from the spell list everyday.

Now, Land Druids get additional spells that they *always* have prepared, depending on the land they choose. *Moon Druids don't have this feature*, so they only have the spells in the regular spell list in PHB 208.

If there are Land spells that are in the regular Druid spell list as well as the additional land spells, it only means that the Land Druid doesn't need to prepare that spell; they always have it prepared. The Moon Druid still has access to the spell, if it's in the Druid's spell list, but he has to prepare it as normal.